# Access Ruby Instance Variable from Included Module

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a Sinatra API file that has following code-

```
require 'json'
require_relative 'api_logger'

include ApiLogger

get /myapi/:id
 request_params = request.env
 write_log('log message')    
end
```

Then I have a module containing the methods 'write_log'-

```
module ApiLogger

def write_log(message)
 file.write(request['user']+message)
end
```

But request['user'] is coming out blank.

So the question is how to access the request variable from Sinatra API file in ApiLogger module? Also, I'm creating service class objects from API class and pass them request object at initialization. Can the module 'ApiLogger' access that 'request' instance variable from service class if the service classes just include 'ApiLogger'?

Answer (score 2):

You could pass it as an additional argument.
Something like:

```
require 'json'
require_relative '../../lib/helpers/api_logger'

include ApiLogger

get /myapi/:id
  request_params = request.env
  write_json_log('log message', request)    
end
```

and

```
def write_json_log(message, request)
  file.write(request['auth_subject']+message)
end
```

Comment: Yes, the object `request` is local to the route blocks (`get`, `post` and other sinatra DSL methods), so it's not visible outside. The cleanest way to solve this is to follow this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did not want to pass request object to each method. So I made 'request_params' a global variable in all classes that need to log and added this line in 'ApiLogger' to fetch the value of request object-

```
request = instance_variable_get '@request_params'
```

Comment: Using a global variable like that is a very bad idea. As soon as you start using a server that can handle multiple requests simultaneously (understand multi-threaded), you'll experience strange bugs because your global variable will be updated by a second request while the first one is still running. I strongly suggest against it.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, all you needed was include your module in the helpers in order to have a direct access to the request object. Here's a slightly modified version of your code that runs as a standalone program:

```
require 'sinatra'

module ApiLogger
  def write_log(message)
    $stdout.write(request.env['sinatra.route'] + message)
  end
end

helpers do
  include ApiLogger
end

get '/test' do
  write_log('log message')

  'ok'
end
```